# Using the addPoints feature in chartSeries

Tags: r

Error when using the `addPoints()` function of chartSeries {`quantmod`} library

I'm trying to add points to a chartSeries plot and cannot seem to find a solution.  I'm using the `addPoints()` function for the first time but always get the error

> Error in addPoints(AAPL["2018-08", 6]) : x and y must be of equal lengths

I don't know what this error message means or how to correct it.

```
library (quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
chartSeries(AAPL["2018-08"])
addPoints(AAPL["2018-08",6])
```

I'm expecting that it's going to add a point on the chart for each day representing the adjusted price, column 6 from the getSymbols time series, but I keep getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently we need to provide both `x` and `y`, where your data corresponds to `y`:

```
chartSeries(AAPL["2018-08"])
addPoints(x = 1:nrow(AAPL["2018-08"]), y = AAPL["2018-08", 6])
```

[image]

Comment: This works great!  I'm also using conditional logic to determine which x coordinates need a data point.  Regardless of the time series value in the xts matrix used in the addPoints() function, it always begins plotting on the first x coordinate.

Comment: @SNovogoratz, no problem. I'm not sure what you mean though, is what you described a problem? `addPoints(y = AAPL["2018-08",6][1], x = 5)` doesn't start from `x = 1`, if that helps.